# How to get correct return an array for ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json, datatable

I'm using the api dataTable and ajax.

I generate an array like this:

```
[['1','2','3'],['4','5','6']]
```

On my return from ajax, and does not work in dataTable, but if I copy this array and put in:

```
success: function (result) {
    result = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6']];
}
```

Example script:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('pagseguro/adminhtml_ajax'); ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: { 
                        form_key: "<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?>", 
                        days: getDays
                        },
                success: function(result) {
                    if (result != "") {
                        jQuery('#htmlgrid').dataTable().fnClearTable(true);           
                        jQuery('#htmlgrid').dataTable().fnAddData(result);
                        //jQuery('#htmlgrid').dataTable().fnStandingRedraw();
                    }

                    blockModal(0);
                },
                error: function() {
                    blockModal(0);
                }
            });
```

Works, already tried dozens of ways to return in json array and do not know why to return and php does not work with the array placed physically in the script works.

Example 1 php:

```
print_r($array) = array ([0] => Array ( [date] => 15/07/2014 [id_magento] => #100000031 [status_magento] => Pendente) 
   [1] => Array ( [date] => 15/07/2014 [id_magento] => #100000030 [status_magento] => Pendente))
```

Processing `$array` code:

```
foreach ($array as $info) {

                $i = 1;
                $dataSet .= ($j > 1) ? ",[" : "[";              

                foreach ($info as $item) {

                    $dataSet .= (count($info) != $i) ? "'" . $item . "'," : "'" . $item . "'";          
                    $i++;   

                }

                $dataSet .= "]";
                $j++;

            }

            $dataSet .= "]";
            echo $dataSet;
```

Example 2 php:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Show us the code how you generate and send the JSON array to the browser.

Comment: Ouch... why would anyone manually (and badly) even try to generate a JSON string, if you have a function like `json_encode($array);` at your disposal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acoording to your code you've posted. There are a PHP function and a HTTP header which you should read about.

- Function [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php)
- Header [`Content-Type: application/json`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_Headers)

So you end up with something like

```
// Tell browser it'll receive JSON data
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 

// Parses your array as a valid JSON string
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: It's just a concept. Adapt it to your specific case.

Comment: apparently worked, but does not return the data in the table, only creates the trd and no tds given

Comment: Well if your ajax request receives now valid and usable json data from server this question is solved. If something else on client site does not work. Open a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {

    }
    success: function(aData) {
         console.log(aData);
    }
});
```

DataType is missing in your [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Should help or try $.parseJSON(yourJsonString)